# Data table not getting returned through WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datatable

I am trying to return a Class object as `DataContract` through `WCF Webservice`. This class object has a `DataTable(DataMember)` as property which is getting loaded in the webserivce method but is not getting assigned to the `DataTable` at the client side. Below is the code I am trying to run.

DataContract Definition:

```
[DataContract]
public class RelationshipDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public DataTable AllRelationships { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DataTable RelationshipTypes { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DataTable ContactFrequencies { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DataTable ObjectiveTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Interfaces:

```
    [OperationContract]
    RelationshipDetails GetRelationshipTypes(string spaceId, ref string message);

    [OperationContract]
    RelationshipDetails GetContactFrequencies(string spaceId, ref string message);

    [OperationContract]
    RelationshipDetails GetObjectiveTypes(string spaceId, ref string message);
```

Definition of Interfaces

```
    public RelationshipDetails GetRelationshipTypes(string spaceId, ref string message)
    {
        RelationshipDetails rd = new RelationshipDetails();
        objBAL = new BAL();
        rd.RelationshipTypes = objBAL.GetRelationshipTypes(spaceId, ref message);
        return rd;
    }

    public RelationshipDetails GetContactFrequencies(string spaceId, ref string message)
    {
        RelationshipDetails rd = new RelationshipDetails();
        objBAL = new BAL();
        rd.ContactFrequencies = objBAL.GetContactFrequencies(spaceId, ref message);
        return rd;
    }

    public RelationshipDetails GetObjectiveTypes(string spaceId, ref string message)
    {
        RelationshipDetails rd = new RelationshipDetails();
        objBAL = new BAL();
        rd.ObjectiveTypes = objBAL.GetObjectiveTypes(spaceId, ref message);
        return rd;
    }
```

Now in the above definition, I am able to load data tables into the `DataTable` properties of the `rd` object. The peroblem is when I use this method in the client application, the `datatable` does not get populated. Below is the client side code.

```
    SpaceServiceClient ssc = new SpaceServiceClient();
    string message = "";
    string gUserName = "";
    string gSpaceId = "";
    string gSpaceName = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gUserName = Session["gUserName"].ToString();
        gSpaceId = Session["gSpaceId"].ToString();
        //gSpaceId = "1";
        gSpaceName = Session["gSpaceName"].ToString();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadRelationshipTypes();
            LoadContactFrequencies();
            LoadObjectiveTypes();
        }
    }

    void LoadRelationshipTypes()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ssc.GetRelationshipTypes(gSpaceId, ref message).RelationshipTypes;
        gvRelationshipTypes.DataSource = dt;
        gvRelationshipTypes.DataBind();
    }

    void LoadContactFrequencies()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ssc.GetContactFrequencies(gSpaceId, ref message).ContactFrequencies;
        gvContactFrequencies.DataSource = dt;
        gvContactFrequencies.DataBind();
    }

    void LoadObjectiveTypes()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ssc.GetObjectiveTypes(gSpaceId, ref message).ObjectiveTypes;
        gvObjectiveTypes.DataSource = dt;
        gvObjectiveTypes.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8994622/17447

Comment: You want to make RelationshipDetails rd a global variable no inside any mehtod.  Your code will only get back one table at a time and not all 4 together.

Comment: @jdweng: Why would I need to make rd as Global variable while my method is already returning a the RelationshipDetails type. As well, this way is working well for all other datatables but these three. Also, I know my code is returning one datatable table at a time which is fine for me.

Comment: @naveen: I have already given names to my table. My problem is that the same code was working till yesterday and suddenly it has stopped working.

Comment: is your datatable null. do you have a logger in wcf? are the rows empty? also a logger in the catch block might help

Comment: @naveen: Yes, my datatable is showing null. I do not have idea about logger. Some information would help.

Comment: RelationshipDetails only contains on valid DataTable at a time with your code. You are performing 'new RelationshipDetails()' every time you fetch a DataTable which is setting the other three DataTables to null.

Comment: If you *must* use `DataTable`s in WCF (which I strongly discourage), you need to give them a name, otherwise it won't serialize.

Comment: @Tim: I have given these tables a name. These tables were getting fetched  perfectly two days before. I am afraid that I might have changed anything accidently which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: @braceyourself - Where did you assign names to them?  I don't see it in your posted code.

Comment: @Tim Within the definition of Interface: I am using `objBAL.GetRelationshipTypes(spaceId, ref message)` to set Data into to `dt` object; and the method handles the getting data from server and setting name of the table and it also return the table as a result.